# Python: How do I solve ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='data.humdata.orghttps', port=443)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to download data from this [site](https://data.humdata.org/search?q=&sort=if%28gt%28last_modified%2Creview_date%29%2Clast_modified%2Creview_date%29%20desc&ext_page_size=100&ext_administrative_divisions=1&page=1) with countries' data. I successfully scraped the page contents and obtained the download links from each of the country, especially the links having .zip files.

A sample of my code that collects the file download links is as follows:

```
data = soup.find_all('div', {"class":'hdx-btn-group hdx-btn-group-fixed'})

for item in enumerate(data):
            if '.geojson' in item.get_text() or '.topojson' in item.get_text():
                continue
            elif 'ADM0' in item.get_text() or 'ADM1' in item.get_text() or 'ADM2' in item.get_text() or 'ADM3' in item.get_text():
                a_links = item.find('a', href=True)
                split_link = str(a_links).split('"')
                index_link = 0
                for val,every in enumerate(split_link):
                    if every == ' href=':
                        index_link = val + 1
                
                our_link = split_link[index_link]
                full_link = new_base_url + our_link
                all_new_links[m]['link'].append(full_link)
                all_new_links[m]['country'] = country_name
```

Here, as a sample, is the list of file download links:

```
file_download = ['https://data.humdata.orghttps://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/raw/ba7b3ab481359205226ac8712f07326d6a7edb3d/releaseData/gbOpen/ZMB/ADM2/geoBoundaries-ZMB-ADM2-all.zip', 'https://data.humdata.orghttps://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/raw/4e9bd60a361c465be0bca5487f4e3d496a27d0be/releaseData/gbOpen/YEM/ADM2/geoBoundaries-YEM-ADM2-all.zip', 'https://data.humdata.orghttps://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/raw/eff4a77b014f07e326e04eeb24bc81de2a45f64f/releaseData/gbOpen/WSM/ADM2/geoBoundaries-WSM-ADM2-all.zip', 'https://data.humdata.orghttps://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/raw/3a56abbc5fdde21f7dee6ddb9062171da5689b6b/releaseData/gbOpen/VUT/ADM3/geoBoundaries-VUT-ADM3-all.zip','https://data.humdata.orghttps://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/raw/f591db4ef2ab61b972fce008c7addd287d46c846/releaseData/gbOpen/TZA/ADM3/geoBoundaries-TZA-ADM3-all.zip', 'https://data.humdata.orghttps://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/raw/b62f4ea59d20c9b258718a3c845b8bb12c7458f0/releaseData/gbOpen/UGA/ADM2/geoBoundaries-UGA-ADM2-all.zip']
```

Here is my code for downloading the content files

```
z = 1
for i in file_download:
    with open(basename('country'+str(z)+'.zip'), "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(i).content)
        print(f"Item {z} Finished")
z += 1
```

However, when I run the above code to download the data files (zipped in this case), I get the error:

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='data.humdata.orghttps',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
> //github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/raw/ba7b3ab481359205226ac8712f07326d6a7edb3d/releaseData/gbOpen/ZMB/ADM2/geoBoundaries-ZMB-ADM2-all.zip
> (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection
> object at 0x000000F5E604BEE0>: Failed to establish a new connection:
> [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))

I have tried several things to try and solve the error and haven't been successful. These include adding headers and verify=False

```
z = 1
for i in file_download:
    with open(basename('country'+str(z)+'.zip'), "wb") as f:
        f.write(requests.get(i, headers=headers, verify=False).content)
        print(f"Item {z} Finished")
z += 1
```

How can I solve this error? I will gladly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple error, look at your URLs in file_download, you've prepended the original site address by mistake, eg: 'https://data.humdata.orghttps://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/raw/ba7b3ab481359205226ac8712f07326d6a7edb3d/releaseData/gbOpen/ZMB/ADM2/geoBoundaries-ZMB-ADM2-all.zip' should be 'https://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries/raw/ba7b3ab481359205226ac8712f07326d6a7edb3d/releaseData/gbOpen/ZMB/ADM2/geoBoundaries-ZMB-ADM2-all.zip'

Note, you could just clone this repo where all these data sets are:
https://github.com/wmgeolab/geoBoundaries

Comment: Thanks G, You're a genius! I couldn't see that at all, maybe coz I worked on it all day. I could have cloned the repo, however, I just need to pick specific files.

Comment: We all know the feeling very well! lol

Answer (score -1):

I maintain geoBoundaries, and would also recommend our own API, which (in my opinion :) ) ) is a little easier to use than HDX:
https://www.geoboundaries.org/api.html

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Dan. I will give it a check. I have a question. I found out that HDX doesn't have all the countries admin data especially Europe and North American countries. Can I get all of them from your API. And also I'm very interested with the geojson files. Is it possible?

Comment: Yep - we've got everything, including geojsons.